# Do Oracle synonyms need to be recreated when the object changes?

Tags: sql, oracle, rename

I have 2 tables:

- **table1** with synonyms schema: **userA.table1**, **userB.table1**
- **table2**

I have used:

- ALTER TABLE **table1** RENAME TO **table1_old**;
- ALTER TABLE **table2** RENAME TO **table1**;

It is necessary to recreate synonyms with drop, create, replace SQL syntax or is safe to use as is synonyms and don't recreate it?

Comment: What does querying `user_synonyms` or `all_synonyms` tell you? And what does querying the synonyms as those users reveal - unless the data in both tables is identical, doesn't that tell you which table is being seen? (This is also nothing to do with PL/SQL...)

Comment: I have tried querying all_synonyms and it is ok. Table can be query it with userA userB. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the reason why but I have had issues in the past with synonyms not working when changes are made to the underlying object. For that reason I recreate the synonyms when I alter tables in that way.

Comment: Thanks for response!

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't need to recreate synonyms if the underlying object changes.

They will be temporarily marked as "invalid" until Oracle re-validates them, which will eventually be done automatically - although it's often a good idea to revalidate them manually (in order to check they are still ok).

```
ALTER SYNONYM usera.table1 COMPILE;
ALTER SYNONYM userb.table1 COMPILE;
```